# C++ function returns object without some fields

Tags: c++, function, pointers, reference

I have a project which creates a schedule and makes an optimization to it. The project has the  Schedule class:

Schedule.h:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef SCHEDULE_H
#define SCHEDULE_H

#include "Course.h"
#include "Prof.h"
#include "Room.h"
#include "TimeBlock.h"
#include "Weekdays.h"
#include "ScoreCalculator.h"
#include <map>
#include <vector>
/**
 * This class represents a schedule for all courses.
 */
class Schedule {
public:
    Schedule(std::vector < Room >, std::vector < Prof >, std::vector < Course > );
    Schedule(const Schedule& schedule);
    std::map < Room, std::vector < std::vector < Course > > > getSchedule();
    bool setCourse(const Course&, const Room&, Weekdays, TimeBlock, int);
    Course getCourse(const Room&, Weekdays, TimeBlock);
    std::vector < Course > getCoursesAt(Weekdays, TimeBlock);
    std::vector < Weekdays > getWeekdaysFor(const Course&);
    TimeBlock getTimeFor(const Course&);
    Room getRoomFor(const Course&);
    void swapCourses(Room, Weekdays, TimeBlock, Room, Weekdays, TimeBlock);
    void setScore (double score){ _score = score; }
    double getScore() { return _score; }
    Prof getProf(string);
    Prof getProf(Course);
    std::vector<Course> getCoursesTaughtBy(Prof&);
    std::vector<Course> getCoursesOnGivenDayTaughtBy(Prof&, Weekdays);
    std::vector<Room> getRooms();
    std::map<string, Prof> getProfs();
    void setSchedule(std::map < Room, std::vector < std::vector <Course> > >);
private:
    std::map < Room, std::vector < std::vector < Course > > > _schedule;
    std::map < std::string, Prof > _professors;
    std::map < std::string, Course > _courses;
    std::vector<Room> _rooms;
    std::vector<Prof> _profs;
    std::vector<Course> _coursesVector;
    double _score;
};

#endif // SCHEDULE_H
```

Schedule.cpp:

```
#include "../include/Schedule.h"
#include "../include/Prof.h"
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

/**
 * Constructor for the schedule. Creates the empty schedule
 */
Schedule::Schedule(vector < Room > rooms, vector < Prof > prof, vector < Course > courses){
    _rooms = rooms;
    _profs = prof;
    _coursesVector = courses;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < prof.size(); i++){
            _professors.insert(make_pair(prof.at(i).getId(), prof.at(i)));
    }
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < courses.size(); i++){
        _courses.insert(make_pair(courses.at(i).getId(), courses.at(i)));
    }
    _score = -1;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < _rooms.size(); i++){
        vector < vector < Course > > dayVector;
        dayVector.resize(WEEKDAYS_SIZE);
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < dayVector.size(); j++){
            dayVector.at(j).resize(TIMEBLOCK_SIZE);
        }
        _schedule.insert(make_pair(_rooms.at(i), dayVector));
    }
}

bool Schedule::setCourse(const Course& course, const Room& room, Weekdays firstMeeting, TimeBlock timeBlock, int numberOfMeetings){
    if (course.getEnrolled() > room.getCapacity()){
        return false;
    }
    _schedule.at(room).at(firstMeeting).at(timeBlock) = course;

    switch (numberOfMeetings){
    case 2:
        _schedule.at(room).at((TimeBlock)(firstMeeting + 2)).at(timeBlock) = course;
        break;
    }
    return true;
}

Course Schedule::getCourse(const Room& room, Weekdays day, TimeBlock timeBlock){
    //returns course
}

vector < Course > Schedule::getCoursesAt(Weekdays day, TimeBlock timeBlock){
    //returns course at the given time
}

TimeBlock Schedule::getTimeFor(const Course& course){
    //returns time for the course
}

Room Schedule::getRoomFor(const Course& course){
    //returns room for the course
}

vector < Weekdays > Schedule::getWeekdaysFor(const Course& course){
    //returns weekdays for the course
}

// returns true if swap was successful, false otherwise
void Schedule::swapCourses(Room room1, Weekdays weekdays1, TimeBlock timeBlock1, Room room2, Weekdays weekdays2, TimeBlock timeBlock2){
    Course c1, c2;
    c1 = getCourse(room1, weekdays1, timeBlock1);
    c2 = getCourse(room2, weekdays2, timeBlock2);
    setCourse(c2, room1, weekdays1, timeBlock1, 2);
    setCourse(c1, room2, weekdays2, timeBlock2, 2);
}

Prof Schedule::getProf(string id){
    return _professors.at(id);
}

Prof Schedule::getProf(Course c){
    return _professors.at(c.getProfId());
}


void Schedule::setSchedule(map < Room, vector < vector < Course > > > schedule){
    _schedule = schedule;
}

map < Room, vector < vector < Course > > > Schedule::getSchedule(){
    return _schedule;
}

vector<Room> Schedule::getRooms(){
    return _rooms;
}

map <string, Prof> Schedule::getProfs(){
    return _professors;
}

vector <Course> Schedule::getCoursesTaughtBy(Prof& prof){
    //returns courses taught by
}

Schedule& Schedule::operator=(const Schedule& rhs){
    _rooms = rhs._rooms;
    _courses = rhs._courses;
    _coursesVector = rhs._coursesVector;
    _professors = rhs._professors;
    _profs = rhs._profs;
    _schedule = rhs._schedule;
    return *this;
}
```

It has a class which handles the optimization by swapping two random courses and deciding, which schedule is better:

GeneticScheduleGenerator.h:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef GENETICSCHEDULEGENERATOR_H
#define GENETICSCHEDULEGENERATOR_H

#include "ScheduleGenerator.h"
#include "ScoreCalculator.h"
#include "Schedule.h"
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class GeneticScheduleGenerator : public ScheduleGenerator {
public:
  GeneticScheduleGenerator(ScoreCalculator&, Schedule*, long);
  Schedule* getSchedule(void);
  Schedule* _schedule;
  map < Room, vector < vector < Course > > > getScheduleMap();
private:
    double calculateScore(map < string, Prof >, Schedule*);
  void optimize ();
  std::map<string, ProfInfo> profInfoMap;
  ScoreCalculator& _sc;
  map<string, double> _scores;
  map<Room, vector< vector< Course> > > _scheduleMap;


};

#endif // GENETICSCHEDULEGENERATOR_H
```

GeneticScheduleGenerator.cpp:

```
#include "../include/GeneticScheduleGenerator.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include "../include/Weekdays.h"
#include "../include/TimeBlock.h"
#include <iostream>

GeneticScheduleGenerator::GeneticScheduleGenerator(ScoreCalculator& sc, Schedule* schedule, long timeout )
    : ScheduleGenerator(timeout) , _sc(sc) {
        _schedule = schedule;
}

double GeneticScheduleGenerator::calculateScore(map<string, Prof> professors, Schedule* schedule){
    double score = 0;
    //does some calculations
    return score;
}

Schedule* GeneticScheduleGenerator::getSchedule(){
    Schedule* bestSchedule = _schedule;
    Schedule _changedSc = *_schedule;
    Schedule *_changedSchedule = &_changedSc;
    map<string, Prof> professors = bestSchedule->getProfs();

    bestSchedule->setScore(calculateScore(professors, bestSchedule));

    srand(time(NULL));
    vector<Room> rooms = _schedule->getRooms();
    int numberOfRooms = rooms.size();
    Room room1, room2;
    Weekdays day1, day2;
    TimeBlock time1, time2;

    long endTime = time(0) + getTimeout();
    int counter = 0;
    do{
        counter++;
        room1 = rooms.at(rand() % numberOfRooms);
        room2 = rooms.at(rand() % numberOfRooms);
        day1 = (Weekdays)(rand() % WED);
        day2 = (Weekdays)(rand() % WED);
        time1 = (TimeBlock)(rand() % TIMEBLOCK_SIZE);
        time2 = (TimeBlock)(rand() % TIMEBLOCK_SIZE);
        if (_changedSchedule->getCourse(room1, day1, time1).getEnrolled() > room2.getCapacity() ||
            _changedSchedule->getCourse(room2, day2, time2).getEnrolled() > room1.getCapacity() ||
            _changedSchedule->getCourse(room2, day2, time2) == _changedSchedule->getCourse(room1, day1, time1))
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            bestSchedule = _schedule;


            _changedSchedule->swapCourses(room1, day1, time1, room2, day2, time2);
            double newScore = calculateScore(professors, _changedSchedule);

            if (bestSchedule->getScore() > newScore){
                _schedule = _changedSchedule;
                _schedule->setScore(newScore);
            }
        }

    } while (time(0) < endTime);
    std::cout << "counter: " << counter << endl;
    _scheduleMap = _schedule->getSchedule();
    /*map<string, Prof> tempProf = _schedule->getProfs();
    map<string, Course> tempCorse = _schedule->getCourses();*/

    return _schedule;
}

map < Room, vector < vector < Course > > > GeneticScheduleGenerator::getScheduleMap(){
    return _scheduleMap;
}
```

The ScheduleGeneratorClass is not yet fully functioning(it does not test for class conflicts, i.e. same professor can't teach 2 classes at the same time), but it swaps classes and calculates the score for the schedule. The problem is, that before the return _schedule; part _schedule contains the valid schedule:

[image]

But when the caller gets it, the object holds only the score part. Everything else seems to be erased:

[image]

I have been trying to solve that for last couple of days and had no luck.
Can anyone help?
If you need the other code or more info, just ask.
Thank you.

Comment: Too much code, you need to make a minimal example!

Comment: TMC;DC. Can you narrow your code down a bit?

Comment: Too much code and not enough, how are your types used? In particular, what is the second argument to the `GeneticScheduleGenerator`?

Comment: it is the original schedule

Comment: stop using pointers. It's no coincidence that the problem in that huge amount of code happens to be just where you stopped using nice objects and references, and started using a pointer!

Comment: I got rid of some code, so now it is not as big as it used to be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `getSchedule` these lines of code:

```
Schedule _changedSc = *_schedule;
Schedule *_changedSchedule = &_changedSc;
```

creates a **local** instance of `Schedule` on the stack and a pointer to that local instance.

This line of code:

```
_schedule = _changedSchedule;
```

means that `_schedule` now points to that local variable.

When your method returns, the local variable goes out of scope, so your `_schedule` pointer is now invalid.

The reason the vector sizes change back to zero is probably due to the vector destructor, but there is nothing stopping the program reusing that memory for something else and you would then get a segfault if you tried to use the vectors.

One way to fix it is to have a more permanent place to store the changed `Schedule`, e.g. in the class itself. Another is to pass in a `Schedule` object to be filled in. Yet another way is to pass back the `Schedule` as an object, rather than a pointer.

Comment: I'm now returning schedule as an object and it works fine! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use the `new` operator where you know that object will not be used within the initialised scope. For example:

`Schedule *_changedSchedule = &_changedSc;`

when `_changedSc` goes out of scope, it will not be in the stack anymore. You need to be able to store that in the heap by using the `new` operator.

Comment: ITYM the *new expression*. And this is poor advice because it means the caller will now have to manually manage memory. OP does need to fix that piece of code, but throwing `new` at it is not the way to go.

Comment: Then OP has to use within the scope of local variable